# R - Rselenium - setImplicitWaitTimeout gives error in Selenium Server 3.5.3

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

This Rselenium command works when using Selenium Server 3.4.0 and Gecko Driver v0.18.

```
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 15000)
```

Here's the relevant code block:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)   
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 15000)
```

But when running Selenium Server 3.5.3 with either Gecko v0.18 or v0.19, the same code generates this error:

```
Selenium message:POST /session/91a1f43f-18b3-4e11-92a9-d738cd4049a4/timeouts/implicit_wait did not match a known command
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'pc', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.x', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: UnknownCommand
 Detail: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.
 class: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException
 Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Firefox:  55.0.3 (64-bit)

I've looked for package updates in the Rselenium Github repo and have searched for other info.

Not sure if I'm missing something or should report a bug.

Comment: Firefox/geckodriver is partially through implementing the w3c webdriver spec. See https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/143 etc. Use chrome or an older version of firefox via docker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation of implicit wait is now slightly different. Try

```
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$setTimeout(type = "implicit", milliseconds = 5000)
```

You may also wish to set the pageload timeout

```
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SetTimeouts command maps to the Marionette setTimeouts command, which makes geckodriver compatible with Firefox 56 and greater.

from their release information on github. you should use firefox 56 or greater instead of 55.

[here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) is the link.

Comment: The latest Firefox release as of 9/18/17 is 55.0.3 (64-bit being used).  Are you suggestion to wait for 56 or that 56 is available somewhere other the Firefox releases webpage?  I plan to roll back to a previous version which was working fine with Selenium Server 3.5.3 and Gecko v0.18